# Mismatch error 13 in Excel VBA 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've spent hours combing through online resources and cannot find an answer to why this returns an error:

```
Sub temp()

Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Findtext = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B500").Value
Replacetext = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A500").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Each time I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" message.

I'm just trying to replace numerical values in one sheet with words from another sheet that have corresponding numerical values in the adjacent column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B500").Value
```

returns a 2D Variant array with bounds (1 to 499, 1 to 1), not a string.

You can't do this the way you're trying to: you can instead loop over each pair of values and run a replace for each pair.

Untested:

```
Sub temp()

Dim Findtext As String
Dim Replacetext As String
Dim rw As Range

    For Each rw In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B500").Rows

        Findtext = rw.Cells(2).Value
        Replacetext = rw.Cells(1).Value

        If Len(Findtext) > 0 Then

            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
    Next rw

End Sub
```